# Swift UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UISwitch

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to add the UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a switch created programmatically

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
var newSwitch: UISwitch!
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

func CreateSwitchWithIndex(index:Int) {
let newSwitch = UISwitch()
newSwitch.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
newSwitch.on = false
self.view.addSubview(newSwitch)

var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "menu:")
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1
newSwitch .addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    if(touch.view == newSwitch){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
 }}
```

the longpress on the switch I get it only if I press just below the switch itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. After that you can disable all touches for your slider. That way, the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` should work.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        //disable recognition of touches on the switch

        if(touch.view == newSwitch){
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create a global switch-variable outside of your function in your class body: `var yourSwitch:UISwitch!`. After that in your method where you create it, just create it like that: `yourSwitch = UISwitch()`